# Sequences base $m$

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Please give me a hint on the following question.

Given $x \in [0, 1]$ show that there exist $a_1, a_2, a_3,...\in S_m$ such that 
for $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{m^k}$ we have $x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n$.

I'm not good at proving existence questions.

Comment: What is $S_m$ ?

Comment: @Fred It's some set that depends on $m\geq 2$ and $m$ is an integer.

Comment: What do you mean it's "some set"?  Can we pick $S_m$?

Comment: @lulu Yes, you can. I think the question asks to prove the existence of base-m of a real number.

Comment: As a guess (but it's just a guess) you are just asking about the base $m$ "decimal" expansion of $x$.

Comment: But in that case, you can not choose $S_m$...it has to be $\{0,\cdots,m-1\}$.  Oh, and we need $m>1$.

Comment: Hint:  use the Greedy Algorithm.  Start by subtracting the greatest multiple of $\frac 1m$ less than $x$.  Then, of course, we have $x-\frac {a_1}m<\frac 1m$.  Now subtract the greatest multiple of $\frac 1{m^2}$ you can from that.  We get $x-\frac {a_1}m-\frac {a_2}{m^2}<\frac 1{m^2}$.  Repeat.